# Save state of a widget

Tags: flutter

I have a button that pushes a page where user fills some data and they can then exit the page but come back and edit it.

I provided a simplified example, the goal is to be able to maintain the counter of "count page" after exiting it without having to save the counter in some other variable. I want a general way to save the state of a widget.

So in other words I don't want the state disposed, I want to save that so when I navigate back to that page it's like I never popped it.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Save State',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          child: Text("Go to counter page"),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => CounterPage()));
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CounterPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CounterPageState createState() => _CounterPageState();
}

class _CounterPageState extends State<CounterPage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text("Go back"),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should read more about [State Management](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options), there are many options and you should choose what you prefer.

If you just want some simple way to get the result of a "page", just return the counter value from the `Navigator.pop`.

Comment: Hey! I don't think you understood my question correctly. My page has a lot of data stored in its state and I'd like to somehow preserve that state and use it again when navigating to that page later rather than have its data reset. The counter is just an example as i mentioned

Comment: That's what state management about. The value is not stored in your widget class but instead in other separate class.

Comment: Ah I see what you meant thank you, I wonder how feasible this would be as I have around 14 of those pages :P Will take a look though thanks!

Comment: You need to study state management, I can't give you a straight answer as there are many possibilities that depend on your particular code.